# Type inference not working as intuited in Swift 3

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, type-inference

I have the following function in the (as-yet unreleased) Swift 3 version of my [CDQI framework](https://github.com/Prosumma/CoreDataQueryInterface/tree/master) for Core Data:

```
public func subquery<E: EntityAttribute>(
    _ items: E, 
    _ query: (E) -> NSPredicate
) -> ExpressionConvertible 
where E: ExpressionConvertible
```

When I use this method, I would expect Swift's type inference to figure out what the exact type of `E` is, based on the first parameter, so I could say this:

```
subquery(department.employees) {
    some($0.lastName.cdqiBeginsWith("S", .caseInsensitive)
}
```

I'd expect `$0` to be an instance of `EmployeeAttribute`, which is the type of the `employees` property of the `department` instance. But it isn't. Swift tells me that it's just `EntityAttribute`, the supertype of `EmployeeAttribute`. To make it work, I have to do the following:

```
subquery(department.employees) { (employee: EmployeeAttribute) in
    some(employee.lastName.cdqiBeginsWith("S", .caseInsensitive)
}
```

This makes the `subquery` function more verbose and less useful.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to make this work without having to give type evidence in the closure? (Note that I'm interested in doing this as a *function* and **not** a method. There will be a corresponding method, but I need to make the function work first.)

Comment: I downloaded the cdqi5 branch of your project and in testNumberOfDepartmentsWithEmployeesWhoseLastNamesStartWithSUsingSubquery, replaced the subquery closure by `{ some($0.lastName.cdqiBeginsWith("S", options: .caseInsensitive)) }`, without having any issues. The test compiles and runs. Also cmd-click on `$0` shows that the compiler infers it as `EmployeeAttribute`.

Comment: OK, I think I may have been the victim of a ghost in the Xcode machine. The compiler told me something to the effect of 'EntityAttribute has no member `lastName`'. Cleaning and rebuilding did not help. But I restarted Xcode and now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem. Here's a highly simplified skeleton of what you're doing:

```
class A {}
class B:A {}
func f<T:A>(thing:T, _ closure: (T)->Void) {}
```

And now we call it and look at what the compiler tells us about the inferred type:

```
f(thing:B()) {
    let what = $0 // compiler says `what` is a B
}
```

So I would have to conclude that in your question you are not completely represented what is going on in your own code.

Comment: According to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable, stating that you cannot reproduce the problem described in the question is not an answer.

Comment: @MartinR My answer is in fact right. The OP can't reproduce the problem either. Moreover my answer is not that I can't reproduce the problem but that stuff must be going on beyond what the OP revealed / described in his question. Finally, I think showing the OP how to test type inference is in fact of great utility and is an excellent way to help him. (Testing skeleton code in a new clean project outside of your project is a very important technique.) However, if you don't like it, downvote it and flag it! It's a free world.